# Django - retrieve url from HttpResponse object?

Tags: python, django

In Django test cases, how do you get the url from a `HttpResponse` object?

If I have the following Django app:

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('httpresponse/', views.http_response, name='http_response'),
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def http_response(request):
    return render(request, template_name='home.html')
```

### tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

http_response = reverse('http_response')

class TestTemplateResponse(TestCase):
    def test_http_response(self):
        response = self.client.get(http_response)
        self.assertEqual(response.url, http_response)
```

The unit test fails with the following message:

`AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'url'`.

Is there any way to get the client to return a `Response` object, instead of `HttpResponse`?

Comment: I don't think you can get the URL from the response object - although you can from the request. But I'm struggling to understand why you would want to. The URL belongs with the request, not the response. Django uses it to essentially look up in your `urls.py` which code you want to run to generate an `HttpResponse` object, and when it's got this object, it converts it behind the scenes into an actual HTTP response to send back to the client. The response has nothing to do with the URL to which the original request was made.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to test. An HTTP response in general doesn't have a URL, it returns the content for the URL you requested. Look in your browser, there isn't a URL part to the HTTP raw response. So the `HttpResponse` object also doesn't have a `url` attribute. What one might want to test is whether there have been any redirects or not. But then your response would have a different status code (e.g. 301 or 302) and the response actually does have a `url` property.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you for your reply.  If a user is authenticated and they try to visit the `signup` page, I'm redirecting them to `home`.  I tried writing a unit test for this using `response = self.client.get(...)` and `self.assertRedirects(response, home)` but it kept giving me the error above.  `TemplateResponse` and `HttpResponse` objects can be returned from self.client.get, and they don't have a `url` parameter.

Comment: Add the `follow=True` option to your `get()` call. This will follow redirects and then `self.assertRedirects(response, home)` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

From the code given above and your comment suggesting that you are trying to redirect user to home page if they are authenticated doesn't match up. In the code above if someone is visiting the `/httpresponse` then you are just rendering a template(which returns `HttpResponse`).

`HttpResponse` object doesn't have the `url` property. Now, if you were to use `login_required` decorator with the view you've written, it would redirect `unauthenticated` users to login page. In this case(`redirect`), an `HttpResponseRedirect` instance is returned which indeed has the `url` property.

Django source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d6aff369ad33457ae2355b5b210faf1c4890ff35/django/http/response.py#L465

So, to test if authenticated users are getting redirected to home page view when visiting singup you should first setup the redirect for authenticated users. And then you should be able to access the `url` property of the response.